# Restore permissions to all files in folder using RPM

Tags: permissions, rpm

Using chmod, I accidentally changed everything in a bin folder and now sudo/su doesn't work.

I know *rpm -q --whatprovides* can provide which RPM provides a specific file. and *rpm --setperms* can restore everything provided by a RPM.

Is there a way to restore the permissions of all the files in a folder using rpm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the built-in features don't apply per directory. However the following might be a solution…let's assume you messed up `/usr/bin` permissions recursively, the following might help:

```
rpm --setperms $(rpm -qf $(find /usr/bin) | sort -u)
```

It looks up all elements below `/usr/bin` and queries the RPM database for the corresponding package, deduplicates the RPM packages list and runs `rpm --setperms` for each applicable RPM package.